# how to define different widgets for different rows in dgrid

Tags: editor, cell, dgrid

The dgrid Editor is a column-level plugins, which controls the whole column behavior.

Suppose I have a list of parameters, each has different value type that I want to show in different widgets. For example:

param1      value1(bool, shown as a checkbox) 
param2      value2(string, shown as a text input)  
param3      value3(enum, shown as a combobox)  
param4      value4(int,  shown as a NumberSpinner)  
....

All the values are in the second column in the dgrid, but they are different types. How do I apply the Editor plugin to the cell level? Is there any method I can use to control individual cell in dgrid?

Thanks.